problem with reboot
Running Raspberry Pi OS Lite on a RP5. Just done full upgrade. I am manually mounting my SSD. All appears ok until I tried to reboot and lost the WiFi connection. Pulled the power connector out then re-inserted it. All now OK. Is this normal?

Yeah - RPi 5 seems to be going through a real rough patch with intermittent technical issues lately.

Pi Hut has suggested that turning off wifi power management may help. I've just done that and will report back on any improvement.

let us know if you need help w/ turn off of wifi pwr mgt

Thanks Seamus managed that OK and was able to successfully reboot.

Turning off wifi power management appears to have sorted the problems I was having with losing network connection on rebooting my headless RP5.
